# Template not found error when template file does exist

Tags: craft3

I am getting a Template not found error.

```
Template not found error: case-studies/_category
```

However the template does exist (see screenshot).

[image]

I have tried clearing the template cache but still the issues perssits.

**Update**

I'm doing tests with other files - like image files - uploading them to the server. They are not getting picked up as existing and throw up 404 errors.

**Update - Fixed**

Looks like we moved the server droplet and were uploading files to the wrong location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_category` can only be viewed if it's included in another file, because of the underscore. A twig file with an underscore cannot be loaded directly via the URL.

You may also read [What is with the underscore in twig template filenames?](https://startingcraft.com/articles/what-is-with-the-underscore-in-twig-template-filenames) or [hidden templates](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/#template-paths) from the Craft Docu.

Comment: Work on my local dev version fine so not sure that is the issue :)

Comment: Yes I get the same issue when removing the underscore and adjusting the name in the category settings.

Comment: strange - Maybe because of the dash?

Comment: All the other files in that directory are working without issue

Comment: Bizzar - I'm doing tests with other files - uploading them to the server. They are not getting picked up as existing.

Comment: Did you check if these files permissions are correct?

Comment: Looks like we moved the droplet and were uploading files to the wrong location!